# Is it possible for a translucent <img> to have to affect on the items below it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I have kind of a weird situation, while trying to make a simple chrome plugin. The idea of the plugin is that it constantly overlays a half-transparent image on top of the page you are viewing. To accomplish this, I have the plugin inject JavaScript, which appends an  tag with the following CSS rules:

```
img.class#id {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 9999999;
}
```

This already works, but it introduces a new problem. Since the z-index of the image is intentionally large, it overrides the left and right click actions of the user, on the elements with a lower z-index. I can't change the z-index to be smaller, since that would defeat the purpose of the plugin, and I can't change the transparency of the other things on the page, since there's too much variability. Is there a way to ensure that the page is still usable, even with the image overlayed on it?

Comment: Have you tried declaring `pointer-events: none` on the `img` tag in question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set `pointer-events: none` in css

**Ref:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

> The pointer-events CSS property specifies under what circumstances (if
>   any) a particular graphic element can become the target of mouse
>   events.

- Note that while only mouse events are stated, it is in fact valid for all kinds of pointer events - mouse, touch.

From the possible values:

> `none` The element is never the target of mouse events; however, mouse
>   events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have
>   pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances, mouse
>   events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as
>   appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event
>   capture/bubble phases.

Comment: Link that in the answer and copy/paste the important part to the answer in case that link ever goes down or changes

Comment: You should still edit it so the important parts from that link would be added to the answer. To be honest, no one should adding stuff to your answer, while it is helpful in this case but it was not part of the original answer